# Did Rambam ever refer to the 13 Principles in his other works?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rambam, theology

Rambam lists the 13 Principles as the beliefs which measure one's merits for the world to come, and he writes it as an elaboration of the Mishnaic statement: "*All of the Jewish people, have a share in the World-to-Come*" (see [Rambam_on_Mishnah_Sanhedrin.10.1.16](https://www.sefaria.org/Rambam_on_Mishnah_Sanhedrin.10.1.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Does Rambam refer to those principles elsewhere in his other works?

Comment: If you're asking if Rambam refers to the 13 Principles as such, I don't know. He does cover them in his enumeration of those who don't have a share in the World to Come, in his [Mishneh Torah, Hilkhot Teshvah, chapter 3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.3.6-8?lang=bi&lang2=en).

Comment: @TamirEvan, at https://www.aishdas.org/asp/ikkarei-emunah I note that the Rambam Hil' Teshuvah divides up the principles among the three types of heretic along the same lines as the way R Yosef Albo (Sefer haIqarim) divides shorashim ("roots", principles of faith that are derivable) among his three iqarim (which he uses to mean mandatory first principles).